# Why is the max value of an unsigned int -> 2^n - 1 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a 4 byte `unsigned int`, I have a space of `2^32` values.

The largest value should be 4294967296 (2^32), so why is it 4294967295 (2^32 - 1) instead?

Comment: There are `2^32` distinct values representable in 32 bits - `0` through `2^32-1`

Comment: Because you start with zero. From 0 to 2^32-1 there is exactly 2^32 values.

Comment: I know humanity has a long history of ignoring zero. But you are a programmer. Let's do better.

Comment: *"So the largest integer should be..."* -- Helper question: What is the smallest unsigned integer stored on 32 bits?

Comment: Helper question #2: what is the largest integer number that can be represented on `3` decimal digits? According to your claim, it should be `1000` (`=10^3`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a basic math. Look at this example:

If you had a 1-bit long integer, what would the maximal value be?

According to what you say, it should be 2^1 = 2. How would you repesent a value 2 with just one bit?

Answer (score 1):

Because counting starts from 0.
for 2 bit integer you can have 4 different values. (0,1,2,3) i.e 0 to 2^2 - 1.

(00,01,10,11)

Similarly for 32 bit integer you can have max value as 2^32 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

2^1 occupies 2 bits.
2^32 occupies 33 bits.

But you have only 32 bits. So 2^32 - 1

Answer (score 0):

Basic mathematics.

A bit can represent `2` values.   A set of `n` bits can represent `2^n`  (using `^` as notation to represent "to the power of", not as a bitwise operation as is its default meaning in C++) distinct values.

A variable of `unsigned` integral type represents a sequence containing every consecutive integral value between `0` and the maximum value that type can represent.    If the total number of sequential values is `2^n`, and the first of them is zero, then the type can represent `2^n - 1` consecutive positive (non-zero) values.    The maximum value must therefore be `2^n - 1`.